# Pylint False Positive E1101: Instance of 'Popen' has no 'poll' member

Tags: python, static-analysis, abstract-syntax-tree, pylint

Pylint is returning lots of false positives for the subprocess module:

```
E1101:184,7:resetboard: Instance of 'Popen' has no 'poll' member
E1101:188,4:resetboard: Instance of 'Popen' has no 'terminate' member
# etc.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bug has been identified in the `logilab-astng` package:
http://www.logilab.org/ticket/46273

They have created a new side project called `pylint-brain` which will be a set of plugins and get included in `logilab-astng`. In the meantime, you can clone or download the latest code from here: https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint-brain/overview

The instructions are on the above site, but the basic approach is:

1. Extract `pylint-brain`
2. Rename ".../site-packages/logilab/astng/brain" to ".../site-packages/logilab/astng/brain-old"
3. Copy or soft-link the extracted "brain" folder to ".../site-packages/logilab/astng/brain"
4. Verify pylint still runs an that the `subprocess.Popen` issue is fixed